# Adding onclick handler to existing react component

Tags: reactjs

Consider this

```js
class CarMaker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { super(props); }
    handleEvent() { /* common handler code */  }

    getComponent() {
        let component = null;

        switch(type) {
            case 'hatchback':
                // unique logic about hatchbacks
                // consider attribues computed inside each case
                component = <HatchbackMaker {...hatchbackAttrs} />;
                break;
            case 'sedan':
                component = <SedanMaker {...sedanAttrs} />;
                break;
            case 'truck':
                component = <TruckMaker {...truckAttrs} />;
                break;
        }
        // Is there any way to attach event handler like this dynamically?
        component.onClick = this.handleEvent.bind(component);
        return component;
    }

    render() {
        let arr = [];
        dataList.forEach(function(dataItem) {
            arr.push(this.getComponent(dataItem.type));
        }, this);

        return (<div>{arr}</div>;)
    }
}
```

What's the best way to add onClick handler to an existing component(held in a variable) and bind that component itself as 'this' value?

Comment: No. You shouldn't be dynamically adding events as you would have to use `setState` for this but it's the wrong way of going about it.

This seems like an architecture problem with your code and it's hard to fix with this limited example as you probably shouldn't be using switch statements for components like this. Post your full code so I can help more. Where does dataList come from?

Comment: What code do you have in `handleClick` too?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying about architecture, currently though being able to dynamically add onClick attribute to component will save some repetitive code.

Comment: dataList looks like

[
        {
            title: 'Honda City',
            type: 'sedan',
            shapeSVGURL: '<url>',
            .
            .
            //more properties
            .
        },
        {
            title: 'VW Golf',
            type: 'hatchback',
            otherUniqueAttrs: []
            .
            //more properties
            .
        }
    ]

Comment: handleClick will basically open a dialog with a unique editor for each type -- different view & functionality for each.

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the `onClick` event at the time of assignment

```js
getComponent() {
        let component = null;

        switch(type) {
            case 'hatchback':
                // unique logic about hatchbacks
                // consider attribues computed inside each case
                component = <HatchbackMaker {...hatchbackAttrs} onClick={this.handleEvent.bind(this)}/>;
                break;
            case 'sedan':
                component = <SedanMaker {...sedanAttrs} onClick={this.handleEvent.bind(this)}/>;
                break;
            case 'truck':
                component = <TruckMaker {...truckAttrs} onClick={this.handleEvent.bind(this)}/>;
                break;
        }

        return component;
    }
```

I have shown the props in the above example separate from the attributes since I don't know what these contain, you can pass with the respective `prop attributes` as well.

Comment: "this.handleEvent.bind(this)" in the context of my example 'this' would refer to CarMaker instead of HatchbakMaker/SedanMaker/TruckMaker as desired. I want to bind to a component after it's created.

Answer (score -2):

You want to create the element dynamically instead based on the type that comes through.

**Make sure you change the type to capital letter at start.**

> E.g. "sedan" --> "Sedan"

Or use JS to uppercase it.

```
class Cars extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            carData: []
        };
    }
    OonClickHandler() { 
        /* common handler code */  
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        //Api call to server to get car types just for example
        $.ajax("someUrl", success: (data) => {
            //[ { title: 'Honda City', type: 'sedan', shapeSVGURL: '<url>', . . //more properties . }, { title: 'VW Golf', type: 'hatchback', otherUniqueAttrs: [] . //more properties . } ]
            this.setState({carData: data});
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                //Make sure that type has upper case later at start or use JS to make it so
                this.state.carData.map(car => React.createElement(car[type], {...car, onClick={this.onClickHandler}}))
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Honda extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

        )
    }
}

class VWGolf extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel it's not close to what I asked about, also it doesn't answer the fundamental question -- attaching click event handler to existing component and binding component itself to the handler.

Comment: @BrieuceWayne Well, this is what you want and you don't dynamically attach event handlers.

If the common cars share logic then you lift that logic up the cars class.

Comment: I agree with moving common logic to cars class in your example, and that's exactly why I want to bind component object to handler in CarMaker class in my example so that there would be a single method to handle all types of components.